# Run thread simultaneously inside action Performed for progress bar to show process execution of method only

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, awt

I am trying to add a progress bar to some method processing in Swing. I want to start the progress simultaneously at the start of a method and conclude at the end of it. I have found sample over the net to use `SwingWorker` and assign task. However, in my case I want to do the same in action performed on a button click. which is attached to `btnTest.addActionListener(this);` and implementing below `actionPeformed`. I tried multiple ways to to run two thread simultaneously but none worked as desired,ie, in parallel. Either the bar hung till the button press was released and then progress bar started. Could anyone suggest a way to approach this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (e.getSource() == btnTest) {

        >>>
        1. Add progress BAR thread 1
        2. call the method for with progress bar should start thread 2
        3. start both thread simultaneously 
        4. End progress BAR
        >>>
        } 
}
```

Comment: *"I have found sample over the net to use `SwingWorker` and assign task."* Yes, that's the way it should be done. *"However, in my case I want to do the same in action performed on a button click."* It can be invoked on button click. If you cannot manage that, I suggest editing to add a [mcve] of your best attempt.

Comment: I Agree.  I'm really stuck at invoking Two threads to run simultaneous. Maybe Im not able to understand it. Have to further research and remove flaws in my present code. and thank you for your response. Do you have a sample example for the algo. you suggested!

Comment: *"Do you have a sample example"* SO is neither a code generation machine nor a substitute for a search engine, but see [Concurrency in Swing: Worker Threads and SwingWorker: Tasks that Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for a start.

Comment: Well Said! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at a [SwingWorker](http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/multi-threading-in-java-swing-with-swingworker.html)

I'm going to show you the basics to using one, then let you implement it with the progress bar.

```
SwingWorker<Void, Integer> randomWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>()
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exceptio
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //Generate a bunch of numbers
            int x = 50 * i;

            //Pause in between
            Thread.sleep(100);

            //Store them in the 'chunks' list
            publish(x);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks)
    {
        for(int num : chunks)
        {
            //Get the numbers in the 'chunks' list
            //To use wherever/however you want
            label.setText(String.valueOf(num));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
        //Something to do when everything is done
        label.setText("Finished");
    }
};
```

Then call the execute method of the Swing Worker in your `actionPerformed()`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    randomWorker.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonah going by this approach. I want to get rid of the loops of publishing x. Instead I want to just call methods to run a) background--> actual work Done b) foreground --> progressBAr show..But I see an anomaly that whatever I put in doInBackgroud runs but the process method stuff does not work...something like this....
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
{  SwingProgressBarExample.mainit();
    return null;
}
protected void process(List<Integer> chunks)
{
    doTaskSecondHere();
}      ................Any idea whats going wrong here. What should I publish!

Comment: @yeppe You are going to want to set your progressbar's minimum and maximum values then create some sort of function that returns a number based on how far along you are in the processing. You should then publish that number and retrieve it in the process method and update the progress bar there.

Comment: You could also use a [Indeterminate](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsinganIndeterminateJProgressBar.htm) `JProgressBar` and in the done function just set its visibility to false